# How can I jump out of a loop but carry on at the next iteration?

Tags: php

In PHP, `break` exits a loop at a given point. But is it possible to force the loop to jump to the next iteration at a given point, rather than exiting it completely? Essentially:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $foo; $i++){  
    if ($i == 1){    
        gotoNextIteration;  
    } else {    
        //do something else   
    } 
}
```

Comment: use `continue` statement

Comment: The option everyone has selected as the reason to close this question is... odd.

Comment: besides that, it isn't even the worst question at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `continue` for this purpose

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $foo; $i++){
  if ($i == 1){
    continue;
  } else {
    //do something else
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `continue;` or you can do something like this as well

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $foo; $i++){
  if ($i != 1){
     //do something
  } 
}
```

you don't need anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Yes .. i have built many type of these loops for dynamic content:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        // write table header
    } else if ($i == 20) {
        // write the table footer
    } else {
        // fill the table columns
    }
}
```

This is a basic example, but I use it for data iteration (like image galleries) and dynamic tables, and more. but I bow to Abhik Chakraborty's Answer as i was not familiar with "continue". I love learning new stuff.

Comment: I am lost in trying to work out what 90% of this has to do with answering the question.

Comment: I was trying to address how to perform functions only on certain iterations - I wasn't aware of continue and had used this method before for example on column iterations with if ($i % 3) types of events ... i thought it could be helpful.

Comment: Ahh ok... No worries :-)